# Insert values in database at some intervals from a visual c++ program/project

Tags: database, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, scheduled-tasks

I want to create a visual c++ program that automatically inserts some random values and the current system datetime in the database at particular intervals. I would be using the srand() function for this. I am not sure how to do this. I was able to achieve this using the winForm projects and scheduling it to run every 30 mins using Task Scheduler but the issue is that every time an empty form pops up and until and unless i close it the values are not entered. What i need is that all these happen on their own and the window should not pop up as its empty. Is winform the right way to achieve this and if not then what kinf of project should i choose. Maybe timers, threads...Please shed some light as i am relatively new to this.

Regards

PS: Here's the code

```
 String^ constring = L"datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root";
 MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);
 MySqlCommand^ cmdDataBase = gcnew MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO `data`.`test` (`datetime`,`temp`,`pressure`) VALUES ('"+dt+"','"+rand_temp+"','"+rand_pressure+"');",conDataBase);  MySqlDataReader^ myReader;



try{
         conDataBase->Open();
         myReader = cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();
        //MessageBox::Show("Data Inserted");
         while(myReader->Read()){



     }
    }catch(Exception^ex){
     MessageBox::Show(ex->Message);
 }


Application::Exit();
```

The above code is inside my formload method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please share your code for deeper insight.

the program is writing to the DB the values, but the DB won't be updated(A.K.A committed) until you'll close the connection/do manual commit. again share your code please. i would advise not to use winforms if you don't need a form. you can use a variety of different ways to achieve DB update. for example, you can use `sleep` so the thread will work once in a while(depends on how much u gave him on the sleep method).

in anyway, give us more information so we can help you

**edited**

after the `cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();` use the `MySQLConnection.commit()` in order to commit the transaction. take all your code to the main function rather then in the creation of the form. it doesn't seems you need a form at all, right?

use the Sleep method to wait for some time if you need(read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) for more information or search google.
anything more?

Comment: it tells me commit is not a member function of MySql::Data::MySqlClient

Comment: conDataBase->Commit(); 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/myconnpy_MySQLConnection_commit.html

Comment: is MySqlConnection a class you created?

Comment: it tells me that commit() is not a memeber

Comment: No...all by default..i just did this:  MySqlConnection^ conDataBase = gcnew MySqlConnection(constring);

Comment: i don't know what to say. you can use Close() method, but that's not a good solution for any other example. look at these links for information on the method you should have: http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/mysql/docs/Devart.Data.MySql~Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlConnection_methods.html

Comment: yes i understand....i have used the close method only...may be there is some issue with the configuration...any ways thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use a console application project instead of a winforms project

Answer (score 2):

You should put the code in the "Main" method and not in the constructor of your Form. You do not Need a Form at all...
Also I do not recommend using a console application, because this will popup a Console-Window...

Comment: so i should just write a c++ program (no project) and put the above code inside main???

Comment: You can use your existing Project and just delete the "Form1.h/resx" files... and place your code into the "main" function.

Comment: @kewal: Alternatively you can create a new "CLR|Console Project" and set the Project properties "Linker|System|SubSystem" from "Console" to "Windows" so you remove the console window. The best would be to use C#... so you don´t have a dependency an the CRT!